# Change background color with local.Storage (value)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background-color of an div:

Arrow Box

For this i have to divs wich you can click. The triggerd function saves the local storage value of the "farbe" key.

```
<div class="radior" style="background-color:#8066CC;"    onClick='localStorage.setItem("farbe","#8066CC");hey()'></div>
```

So after that, the value of the key "farbe" is asked. Besides this is makes an case ... I think you better read my code, because think i need some englisch lessons sorry!

```
function hey(){
switch (localStorage.getItem("farbe")){
case "#121212":
var h = "black"

case "#1bc38e":
var h = "turk"

case "#C3594B":
var h = "red"

case "#8066CC":
var h = "lila"
    }
document.getElementsByClassName("arrow_box")[0].style.backgroundColor=""+h+""; ;

   }
```

SOmehow it doesnt function!
Or you watch an example of my problem at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PpsLH/4/ ! Greetings from Germany!

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: hey is not defined

Comment: At the time im studing interface design and im new to javascript i only used jquer, where can i check these erros? Is there a function in dreamweaver? Or online? Thanks

Comment: i just use chrome and javascript console (Ctrl+Shift+J when in chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
hey = function(){
  switch (localStorage.getItem("farbe")){
    case "#121212":
    var h = "black";
    break ;

    case "#1bc38e":
    var h = "turk";
    break ;

    case "#C3594B":
    var h = "red";
    break ;

    case "#8066CC":
    var h = "lila";
    break ;
  }
    document.getElementsByClassName("arrow_box")[0].style.backgroundColor=h;
}
```

By the way, `lila` is not a valid HTML color, so it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove any inline event handlers from your code. Also the whole switch section and changing to named CSS colors seem redundant. Check out this bit of code written in jQuery

```
var box = $('div.arrow_box');

$('body').on('click','div.radior',function(e){
    var color = $(e.target).css('backgroundColor');    
    localStorage.setItem('farbe',color);
    box.css('backgroundColor',color);
});
```

and a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/BaJvC/5/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div  class="arrow_box"><a>Arrow Box</a></div>


<div class="radior" style="background-color:#C3594B;" onClick="localStorage.setItem('farbe','#C3594B');window.hey()"></div>
<br>
<div class="radior" style="background-color:#8066CC;" onclick='localStorage.setItem("farbe","#8066CC");window.hey()'></div>
```

and for javascript

```
window.hey = function ()
{
    var h="";
    if (localStorage.getItem("farbe")=="#121212")
    {
        var h = "black";
    } else
    if (localStorage.getItem("farbe")=="#1bc38e")
    {
        var h = "turk";
    } else
    if (localStorage.getItem("farbe")=="#C3594B")
    {
        var h = "red";
    } else
    if (localStorage.getItem("farbe")=="#8066CC")
    {
        var h = "lila";
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("arrow_box")[0].style.backgroundColor=h+"";
}
```